# "Unfortunately Exchange Service has stopped" and AccountManager

Tags: android

I am working on an Android application that creates user accounts and save/retrieve data remotely in Parse.

I implemented the AbstractAccountAuthenticator and defined a AuthenticatorActivity. In AuthenticatorActvity, I read the userName and UserPassword from TextViews. Then I check if the account already exists or needs to be added to the AccountManager.

I do:

```
String accountName = intent.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
String accountPassword = intent.getStringExtra(PARAM_USER_PASS);
mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(getBaseContext());
final Account account = new Account(accountName, AccountGeneral.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
if(mAccountManager.getPassword(account)==null){
  // The account is not is mAccountManager
  mAccountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, accountPassword, null);
  mAccountManager.setAuthToken(account, mAuthTokenType, authtoken);
}else{
   mAccountManager.setPassword(account, accountPassword);
}
```

My problem is that as addAccountExplicitly will add the account but will open a window saying : "Unfortunately Exchange Service has stopped ". However, everything works fine and I have no bug on LogCat. The data are saved/retrieved on Parse. And after the first logIn the window does not appear again.

Is there someone having and idea to solve my problem?

Comment: I wish! The problem is that it's just a window opening on the phone when I log in. 

And I forgot to add that this window only appear on my phone (nexus 4). On my tablet (nexus 7), it's never happened!

Comment: I found the problem, in fact a while ago but I forgot to add it. 

In the AsyncTask I just need to call the function to sign in ! 

It was a strange bug...